# Uma cor diferente para cada coluna highcharts

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, highcharts

Eu tenho um gráfico de barras horizontais do Highcharts, eu gostaria que cada barra tivesse uma cor, só que monto elas apenas com uma series usando uma consulta em banco, nesse caso só consigo passar uma cor para todo o gráfico.

Pesquisei em vários lugares, não achei nada do Highcharts que me ajudasse com isso.

Comment: cara eu te respondi, mas li de novo sua pergunta, então postei duas maneiras. "apenas com uma series " é uma série ou varias ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para colocar uma cor diferente para cada coluna utilize o atributo colors dentro de series:

```
series: [{       

        type: 'column',
        colorByPoint: true,
        colors: '#fff',
        name: 'Numero de Chamados',
        data: {[0,1,2,3,4,3,5,4,3,3,3,33,3,3,3,3,3,2]},
        showInLegend: true
    },{       

        type: 'column',
        colorByPoint: true,
        colors: '#000',
        name: 'Numero de Chamados2',
        data: {[0,1,2,13,4,3,1511,4,3,31,3,133,3,13,3,3,3,2]},
        showInLegend: true
    }]
```

Se você usar somente uma série é só colocar este código:

```
colorByPoint: true,
```

Comment: veja se é isso que você quer e me avisa, caso nao seja vou editar

Answer (score 0):

Defina a opção colorByPoint como true e defina a seqüência de cores desejada.

```
options = {
    chart: {...},
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            colorByPoint: true
        }
    },
    colors: [
        '#ff0000',
        '#00ff00',
        '#0000ff'
    ]
}
```

[exemplo - jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DwW3m/)

[**Fonte**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737409/set-different-colors-for-each-column-in-highcharts)